# Crystal Report Getting Error on Load Time

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report on my form1 and a button, button will press then report will be loaded. But i am getting this errors.

[image]

[image]

**My Button code is**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = (@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\CrystalReport1.rpt");
    crystalReportViewer1.DisplayToolbar = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Solution Plateform to X86. I think may be your machine is 64 bit and you make instalation for 32 bit only.

[image]